# Initial setup of bim360 to get custom integration

Tags: autodesk-bim360

I have created a new account with autodesk-bim360. When I try to access my BIM360 docs as Account Admin and I navigate to Settings, I cannot find the **Custom Integration** tab. Is there any settings that I should enable somewhere? Thanks!

[sample image of visible custom integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hy5T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Custom Integration is available automatically with the BIM 360 account which has at least 100 active subscrition users.

For development phase, please send an email to bim360appsactivations@autodesk.com with a request to convert your BIM 360 account to a developer account. Include the following information.

- BIM 360 Account Name - the email address you used to create the account.
- BIM 360 Account ID - the account ID generated when you created the account. To find the account ID, click View Account ID at the bottom left corner of the screen.
- Email address of the BIM 360 account admin.

The link below tells more details:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/get-access-to-account/

Comment: can you elaborate  what is "at least 100 active subscrition users." you mean a normal user cannot benefits from Custom integration until it have 100 active users in his workspace ? If so Why do you limit this way this feature ? 

Is it the same for the built in integration (the "app" tabs in the settings) ?

Comment: This is from the description of https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing: <Limited Free Access for Fusion 360, FusionTeam and BIM 360* subscribers.
available only with 100+ active seats to your BIM 360 subscription> . In the link above, a sentence also indicates: <BIM 360 Enterprise (100+ users) license holders have automatic access to the BIM 360 API>.  I do not have an exact answer with such prerequisite. I will check with sales team and get back to you. While you could also email to forge.sales@autodesk.com with any related inquiry directly.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. The comments I got from sales team is:  Access for customers to create custom integrations using BIM 360 APIs or to pre-built integrations with 3rd party companies is a value-added feature of BIM 360.